# Decrementing for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, decrement

I want to have a for loop like so:

```
for counter in range(10,0):
       print counter,
```

and the output should be 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
a = " ".join(str(i) for i in range(10, 0, -1))
print (a)
```

Answer (score 57):

Check out the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) documentation, you have to define a negative step:

```
>>> range(10, 0, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to give the range a -1 step

```
 for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print i
```

Comment: yes but this only goes to 1!

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print i,
```

The range() function will include the first value and exclude the second.

Answer (score 1):

range step should be -1

```
   for k in range(10,0,-1):
      print k
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: It's the same as

for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(i);
}

@abarisone